# Есть ли возможность использовать require в ES6 модулях?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, testng

Я хочу тесты подключить к проекту node.js
у меня используются es6 модули в которых всё подключается с помошью import

```
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import server from "../server";
```

Но подключая chai в проект через import я получаю ошибку.

```
import chai from "chai";
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Есть ли возможность испольлзовать require ES6 модулях ?

Comment: А вы сборщик используете какой-то?

Comment: [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436580/2881286)

Comment: Сборщика теоретически нет, это основное преимущество ES6.
Спасибо прочитал, что по ссылке написанно. оно и есть
  "backend-clientl-dev": "nodemon --experimental-modules server.mjs".
Я как то на статью наткнулся что как то подключают, но не прочитал... вот и думал, может кто тоже читал

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать 
`import * as chai  from 'chai';`